# What does this mean? initWithFrame:CGRectZero]

Tags: iphone

I created switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this.

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

CGRectZero is equivalent to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0).
But, switch is seen in normal size. 
I didn't specified actuall size.
Please explain to me how above code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UISwitch is not customizable, this also applies to the size.

UISwitch overrides `initWithFrame:` and enforces a size appropriate for the control. The size components of the given rectangle are ignored.

Comment: actually UISwitch overrides sizeThatFits: but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Any UIView object can override the frame size by implementing the [sizeThatFits:](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits%3a) method of UIView.  In fact the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) says that:

> a UISwitch object returns a fixed size value that represents the standard size of a switch view